# Two dimensional Fourier Transform and Convolution of a periodic function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

I want to calculate the Fourier transform of the following function
$$
\frac{1}{T}e^{i\omega_n t}e^{-i\omega_m t^\prime}\Theta(t-t^\prime),
$$
where $\omega_n=\frac{2\pi}{T}n$ ($n\in \mathbb{Z}$) and $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function
$$
\Theta(t-t^\prime)=
\begin{cases}
1\, ,\, t-t^\prime\geq 0\\
0\, ,\, t-t^\prime< 0\, .
\end{cases}
$$
Since it depends on two variables the transformation reads as follows
$$
\frac{1}{T^2}\int_0^Tdt\, dt^\prime \, e^{i(\omega_n-\omega_p) t}e^{i(\omega_l-\omega_m) t^\prime}\Theta(t-t^\prime),
$$
the Fourier transform only depends on the frequency differences, so I define $\Delta_{np}\equiv\omega_n-\omega_p$ and $\Delta_{lm}\equiv\omega_l-\omega_m$.
The convolution of a periodic function is defined as
$$
(f*g)(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\int_0^Tdt^\prime f(t^\prime)g(t-t^\prime).
$$
Hence, I interpret the two dimensional Fourier transform as a one dimensional Fourier transform of a convolution where $f(t^\prime)=e^{i(\omega_l-\omega_m) t^\prime}$ and $g(t-t^\prime)=\Theta(t-t^\prime)$. With the substitutions $q=t-t^\prime$ ($dq=dt$) and $t=t^\prime+q$, the integrals can be written as the product of Fourier transforms
$$
\frac{1}{T^2}\int_0^Tdq\,  \Theta(q)e^{i\Delta_{np} q}\int_0^Tdt^\prime\, e^{i(\Delta_{lm}+\Delta_{np}) t^\prime}.
$$
With this substitution, the step function can be omitted because we integrate from $0$ to the fundamental period $T$. Now, if one of the frequency differences are non zero, then the integral vanishes and if both are zero then the integral is rendered $1$. Hence,
$$
\frac{1}{T^2}\int_0^Tdq\,  \Theta(q)e^{i\Delta_{np} q}\int_0^Tdt^\prime\, e^{i(\Delta_{lm}+\Delta_{np}) t^\prime}=\delta_{n,p}\delta_{m,l}.
$$
However, if I go back to my original integral and insert $\Delta_{np}=\Delta_{lm}=0$, I get
$$
\frac{1}{T^2}\int_0^Tdt\int_0^T dt^\prime \, \Theta(t-t^\prime)=\frac{1}{T^2}\int_0^Tdt\int_0^t dt^\prime=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Now which result is the correct one? I have been calculating all day now to figure a way out of this ambiguity. How do I calculate this Fourier Transform of the convolution??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick reply. (I guess $h$ is the step function and $\delta$ the $delta$ distribution.) How can I use the FT of the step function, when it is multiplied by another. Afterall, I am transforming a product of functions.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $H(x_1,x_2) = h(\frac{x_1-x_2}{\sqrt{2}})$ is $\widehat{H}(\xi_1,\xi_2)=\delta(\frac{\xi_1+\xi_2}{\sqrt{2}})\widehat{h}(\frac{\xi_1-\xi_2}{\sqrt{2}})$

Comment: Ok, I see. One could consider the frequency differences simply as the Fourier exponentials. But, the function under consideration is a product of two periodic functions and the Heaviside step function. So my integral is calculate over one period, instead of $-\infty$ to $\infty$....Does that matter?

Comment: I don't understand where you see a convolution. Assume $G(x_1,x_2) = h_1(x_1)h_2(x_2)$, find its Fourier transform, use a change of variable to obtain the FT of $H(x_1,x_2) = h_1(\frac{x_1-x_2}{\sqrt{2}})h_2(\frac{x_1+x_2}{\sqrt{2}})$, extend to the case $h_1,h_2$ are distributions

Comment: The convolution (for periodic functions) is seen in the third and fourth equation $(e^{i\Delta_{l,m}t})*(\Theta(t))=1/\sqrt{T}\int_0^Te^{i\Delta_{l,m}t^\prime}\Theta(t-t^\prime)$.

Comment: @reuns thank you for the hint. But I do not know, what you mean by "extend to the case $h_1$, $h_2$ are distributions" (I'm not that familiar with distributions), and I am also not sure by what kind of parameter change, I could get the desired form. For $t=\frac{z_1+z_2}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $t=\frac{z_1-z_2}{\sqrt{2}}$, I get $\Theta(\sqrt{2}z_2)$...